# Connect Array across files

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm making a javascript game and I have three files. The first file looks something like this:

```
var player_items = [];
```

The second file has a button that pushes an item into the array:

```
player_item.push("sword");
```

In the third file, I have a console log that shows me the items:

```
console.log(player_items);
```

So then when I go to play my game, I can create the item in the second file, but it is not pushing to the third files so I can use them. I have connected all the files with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="player_items.js"/></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your variable global? What does the `console.log` show? Are you sure the scripts run in proper order? What happens if you add another `console.log` just after `push`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's global. It shows an empty array @Oriol

Comment: I assume the typo is just here and not in your code?

Comment: My bad @Toxantron there's not that typo in my code

Comment: Maybe you are logging the array before the value is added. Since we don't have a runnable example, all we can do is guess.

Comment: How are your files ordered in your html file?

Comment: @JoeCurcuru I have the opening html tags, then a script tag with all my JS in it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you say you have one file but you are also saying you have 3 files.

Comment: @JoeCurcuru I have three separate files. The first one (player_items.js), holds the array. Then there are two more files, select.html and play.html. They are all separate files, but I'm trying to link them, in a sense.

Comment: Ok, if you want to include two html files the only way is through injecting them serverside with php or possibly loading them with jquery on the fly. Still not entirely sure if that's what you want to do.

Comment: @JoeCurcuru I want it so the user can choose an item in select.html and use it in play.html, drawing the info from player_items.js . I'm pretty new to JS so sorry if I'm not making sense

Comment: Well you need to understand that a javascript file is read only. Just because two html files share doesn't mean data can be accessed through it. What you need to do is set some server side session variables, this can be done through $_SESSION['x'] in php. Another solution would be to pass the values through a url string to the next file but this leaves a security vulnerability. You have to deal with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to do so I'll post an answer.

In order to get information from a form you will have to use a server-side language such as PHP to do this.

select.html --> play.html

Basic form submission using php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Now there is a way without php but it leaves your values exposed to a URL string. such as mygame.com?x=50&y=70&z=6560

So on select.html we have a form

```
<form action="play.html">
    <input name = "x"></input>
    <input name = "y"></input>
    <input name = "z"></input>
</form>
```

And in game we use javascript to read the parameters in the url using  document.location.search:

```
var x = document.location.search.split("=")[1].split("&")[0]
var x = document.location.search.split("=")[2].split("&")[0]
var y = document.location.search.split("=")[3]
```

But this will leave a vulnerability where someone can inject their own values.

Hope this helps.